# Cell Phone texting

Tags: spoofing, sms

Is it possible for someone to redirect text messages to you from another’s phone? Something weird is going on…over the last few weeks I have received “wrong number”text messages from people with similar motives. They start as “hey (some random name) this is (another random name) followed by a pic of “them” and when I tell them they have the wrong number they respond back and forth as if it’s truly an accident. Without getting into too much detail, is it possible for someone who is linked to my cell phone account to hack into a phone number (twice from another country) and send messages as this person to my phone? They carry on conversations as if they’re that person etc. I believe my ex is acting as other people and baiting me into conversations from random phone numbers. I have never had this happen, but it’s happened now 3 times since our break up, all the same scenario. Please tell me I’m being paranoid and this is in fact not possible.

Comment: If you receive nearly identical messages from different phone numbers then most likely the messages have been generated by the same sender and the sender phone number you see is forged. The world-wide cellular system has a lot of security problems that can be used to such things.

Comment: you're being paranoid. he can cause spam, but (generally speaking) not hack your phone via messaging.

Comment: Not paranoid at all. Got my answer with the “anonymous text messaging reply. I wasn’t worried my phone was being hacked. I was worried he was harassing me from different phone numbers but didn’t know how it was possible. Now I know.

Answer (score 1):

Someone could be using one of the dozens of single / short term use text/email/fax sites. One site could provide a dozen similar numbers that wont come up as valid. Just google "anonymous text messaging" you will see for yourself.

Comment: This. Thank you. I had no idea this was possible, but it literally looks so easy after a quick Google search. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I have used it to receive a verification message from a service as not to give my actual mobile number out - although many are getting wise to it